# Create a properties type display in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a visual basic project and created a form. I need to display a properties sort of dialog box when a button is clicked. The dialog box is similar to any general properties box. A sample picture is given in this [link](http://postimg.org/image/5ut1z54rz/). The display need not be as interactive as in the picture. A basic level display should be fine.

Version used: Visual Studio 2010

I am new to Visual Studio.

The form somewhat looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/e9u06ktcl/). When the "ProxySelect2" button is clicked some calculations are carried out by the code. I wish to display the results like a property dialog.

Regards,

Saurav Agarwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the toolbox and add a propertygrid.
under the properties for the propertygrid set the dock value to RIGHT, and set visible to false.

then in your button click event use this:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If PropertyGrid1.Visible = False Then
        PropertyGrid1.Visible = True
    Else
        PropertyGrid1.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This video helped me learn property grid quick, as a newbie. [link](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iPiwxzF6b30)